# spoj TESTINT time limit exceed

Tags: c++

The code basically adds two numbers. I was wondering if we can optimise it even more and reduce the execution duration. The online judge for [the SPOJ TESTINT problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/TESTINT/) tells me "time limit exceeded".

Here's my code:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main() 
{
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d\n%d", &a, &b);
    printf("%d", a + b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Online code judging systems are bad and SPOJ is the worst of them all.

Comment: No timeout possible there write some more modern code with error checking to see what the real matter is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the problem page:

> both not greater than 200

That's almost certainly a clue. But you shouldn't care.

The real answer to this question is to stop playing with these utterly stupid "online judges" that test nothing of any real value whatsoever. Maybe you could "optimise" this code to be faster, with some assembly or something, but why on earth would you want to? This is about as good as it gets for most real-world practical purposes. Anything else is just a waste of your time, unless you have an extremely narrow and niche use case.

Speaking more opportunely, is it possible that you have misunderstood the requirements of the task, and are trying to read too much input from STDIN? Then your program would be blocking on the rest. This program should not take anywhere near 0.2s. [For me it takes 0.009s](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea7fda326bf89e17).

Comment: Because if your code is taking more than 0.2s then something might be wrong.

Comment: I had the same time and looked for answers elsewhere and finally gave up and did some thing else.Thanks for the quick reply.